# Active X inside Unit-3D for RDP

Tags: c#, winforms, mono, rdp

I have a project that requires creating an Remote Desktop connection inside the Unity 3D (ver 5.3) gaming environment (i.e., I have a game object that inside it displays the content of a remote Operating System with full user control).  Unity uses Mono 2.0 libraries.

I have created a simple WinForm GUI on Mono 2.0 using `AxMSTSCLib.dll` and `MCTSCLib.dll` that works flawlessly on MonoDevelop/Xamarin (see WinForm.cs, below).  However, when running the same code on Unity, the instantiation call "new AxMSTSCLib.AxMsTscAxNotSafeForScripting ()" results in the following Exception:

```
System.NotImplementedException: COM/ActiveX support is not implemented at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.get_CreateParams()
```

[image: Exception Message]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIq8X.png

I have searched `<i>every single forum</i>` on this topic, to no avail (and I'm not interested in connecting via VNC and WebSockets/Socket.IO/JavaScript due to performance and other pesky issues on the remote host).

The AxMSTSC class extends AxHost.cs that is implemented for Unity.  AxHost.cs was last maintained in 2005 by Novel, and does not have CreateParams() and a whole bunch of other methods implemented (instead, it throws the NotImplementedException).

I have obtained AxHost.cs (fully implemented) for .NET 4.x from Microsoft, but to get it to work on Mono 2.0/Unity, I may end up spending months porting .NET 4.x to Mono, which I currently don't have the time (or skills) for.

The fact that my existing implementation already works for Mono 2.0 as is, but fails inside Unity 3D makes me think that the issue is a simple one that for some reason, I'm not simple to see.  I'm having a hard time connecting Visual Studio's debugger to Unity and stepping through the calls to see where in Unity the problem lies.

My DevOps environment is Windows 10 x64, running the latest MonoDevelop/Xamarin/Unity-3D, and the remote OS is Debian Linux running on VirtualBox.

I'm grateful for any recommendations on where the issue may lie.

**If you don't have a technical response, please spare us irrelevant responses such as: "Why are you trying to do that"** or **"that's not possible."**

### WinForm.cs

```
/* RDP on WinForm on Mono 2.0 for Unity-3D ver 5.x */<br>

using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using AxMSTSCLib;

    public class WinForm : Form
    {
        private AxMSTSCLib.AxMsTscAxNotSafeForScripting m_rdpFrame;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button m_btnConnect;
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        public WinForm ()
        {                                                           
            InitializeComponent ();
        }

        public void run ()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles ();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault (false);
            Application.Run (new WinForm ());
        }

        protected override void Dispose (bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null)) {
                components.Dispose ();
            }
            base.Dispose (disposing);
        }

        private void InitializeComponent ()
        {
            this.m_rdpFrame = new AxMSTSCLib.AxMsTscAxNotSafeForScripting ();
            this.m_btnConnect = new System.Windows.Forms.Button ();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize (this.m_rdpFrame)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout ();
            // 
            // rdpFrame
            // 
            this.m_rdpFrame.Enabled = true;
            this.m_rdpFrame.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
            this.m_rdpFrame.Name = "rdpFrame";
            this.m_rdpFrame.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1000, 720);
            this.m_rdpFrame.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // btnConnect
            // 
            this.m_btnConnect.Location = new System.Drawing.Point (846, 738);
            this.m_btnConnect.Name = "btnConnect";
            this.m_btnConnect.Size = new System.Drawing.Size (80, 25);
            this.m_btnConnect.TabIndex = 1;
            this.m_btnConnect.Text = "Connect";
            this.m_btnConnect.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.m_btnConnect.Click += new System.EventHandler (this.btnConnect_Click);
            // 
            // Window
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF (6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size (1024, 768);
            this.Controls.Add (this.m_btnConnect);
            this.Controls.Add(this.m_rdpFrame);
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.m_rdpFrame)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout (false);
            this.PerformLayout ();
        }

        private void btnConnect_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try {
                m_rdpFrame.Server = "192.168.1.102";
                m_rdpFrame.UserName = "root";
                m_rdpFrame.Connect();
            } catch (Exception Ex) {
                MessageBox.Show ("Error Connecting", "Error connecting to remote desktop " + m_txtServer.Text + " Error:  " + Ex.Message, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
```